# Questions that are asked on Shabbos or Yom-Tov

Tags: discussion

It turns out that people are asking questions on this site on Shabbos or Yom-Tov.
Could be that by developing this site we encourage them to violate Shabbos and Yom-Tov. Sort of lifnei' iver or something.

Maybe a sentence like

```
avoid asking here questions on Shabbos and Yom-Tov
```

should be added to the disclaimer?

[here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10380/should-one-light-shabbat-candles-if-friday-is-yom-tov) is a question for example.

Comment: See also: [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4582/shabbos-answering-questions-that-where-asked-on-shabbos), [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2671/do-you-have-to-close-your-blog-website-on-shabbos) and [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2799/what-is-a-good-way-to-make-ones-website-inaccessible-on-shabbat)

Comment: If we add such, it should probably say "Shabbat" rather than "Shabbos". I transliterate it "Shabas", myself, but I think "Shabbat" has the broadest appeal. "Yom-Tov" might need to be replaced by "Jewish holidays" also. See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10389.

Answer (score 6):

It's not lifnei iveir because they would do this aveira without our help.

I don't think it's any worse than editing a Jewish article on Wikipedia. This is not really a Jewish website (we don't control the back-end here), and it could cause more spam (people could have an attitude that since the mods aren't here, they could post garbage and it will seep through). Many Jewish websites are on over Shabbos/Yom Tov (even websites where Frum Jews run the background.)